# C++ const exprssion members for switch case

Tags: c++, switch-statement, constexpr

I would like some way to evaluate a switch-class statement using class members that are not integer or eum.

The real question is how to make those class members `const-expression` i.e. those members must be known as constant at compile-time.

I tried the code below with `static const`, but it works only when in the `case` statements there are integers.

I was looking at new `C++11 constexpr` that would do the job.

What If I have not available that keyword? Is there anyway or trick or anything to allow my class members (non integer or enum) being const expressions?

I am using Linux and g++. Also any g++ specific keyword would be appreciated.

```
  class MyEnum
  {
  public:
    int val_;
    MyEnum(){}
    MyEnum(int v): val_(v){}
    operator int(){return val_;}
    static const MyEnum ALFA;
    static const MyEnum BETA;
    void foo() {
       // do something.
    }
  };

  const MyEnum MyEnum::ALFA(1);
  const MyEnum MyEnum::BETA(2);

  void testEnum()
  {
    MyEnum val = MyEnum::ALFA;

    switch(val)
    {
      case 0: //works
      //case MyEnum::ALFA:// doesn't work
      cout << "ciao" << endl;
      break;
      case 1: //works
      //case MyEnum::BETA: // doesn't work
      cout << "bello" << endl;
      break;
      default:
      break;
    } 
  }
```

Comment: What about [typecast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) your const MyEnum to int? :)

Comment: what do you want really is to compare value of MyEnum. why not if( val == MyEnum::ALFA) //...

Comment: Do you know that `MyEnum::ALFA == MyEnum::BETA` (and that you are initializing both to zero?)

Comment: Hi! Sorry I edited the code. The class has also to do something so it needs to have methods as well.

Comment: @RaNdoM_PoWneD: I tried case static_cast<int>(MyEnum::ALFA) and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Massa: I edited to return different value. I need a way to evaluate MyEnum::ALFA as const-expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class MyEnum { ALFA, BETA };

int main() {
    MyEnum a = MyEnum::BETA;

    switch( a ) {
        case MyEnum::ALFA:
            std::cout << "ALFA\n";
            break;
        case MyEnum::BETA:
            std::cout << "BETA\n";
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

As per Edward's comment, below, here goes an example of how you can have this without `enum` (in my case, `enum class` -- that creates a new type) or `int`:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyEnum {
    struct Alfa { constexpr operator int() const { return 0; } };
    struct Beta { constexpr operator int() const { return 1; } };
    int v;
public:
    constexpr static Alfa ALFA {};
    constexpr static Beta BETA {};
    MyEnum(const MyEnum&) = default;
    constexpr MyEnum(Alfa vv): v(vv) {}
    constexpr MyEnum(Beta vv): v(vv) {}
    constexpr MyEnum() : MyEnum(ALFA) {}
    operator int () const { return v; }
};

int main() {
    MyEnum a = MyEnum::BETA;
    a = MyEnum::ALFA;

    switch( a ) {
        case MyEnum::ALFA:
            std::cout << "ALFA\n";
            break;
        case MyEnum::BETA:
            std::cout << "BETA\n";
            break;
    }
}
```

That is far more complicated ([live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34d7981e9eb95633)) :D

Comment: This is reasonable code, but it seemed that the question asked for something a little different.  Specifically the first line asked for a switch "using class members that are not integer or enum".

Comment: @Massa: your solution is intreaguing me but unfortunately it doesn't build in g++. I noticed that it has coded with clang which I can't use for my purposes.

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile it worked for me on g++, too ([see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84496d026780ceb7)); what is the problem you are having?

Comment: @Massa forget about my comment. I have just realized that I have g++ 4.4 ..too old for constexpr

Comment: @Massa: Great stuff! At the end I tried your second solution and it works fine even using member of a class that it is what I was also looking for. The use of constexpr in the second example is great.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do something like what I think you're asking.  I've modified your `MyEnum` class so that it is `` `constexpr `` and the variable `val` so that it's `int`. `ALFA` and `BETA` are instances of `MyEnum` rather than both instances and members as in your original code.  Just to make things interesting, the cast operator does more than simply passing back the internal `data`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyEnum
{
public:
    constexpr MyEnum(int n) : data(n) {}
    constexpr operator int(){return data+5;}
private:
    int data;
};

static constexpr MyEnum ALFA{0};
static constexpr MyEnum BETA{1};

void testEnum()
{
    int val = 5;

    switch(val)
    {
    case int(ALFA):
        cout << "ciao" << endl;
        break;
    case int(BETA):
        cout << "bello" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    } 
}

int main()
{
    testEnum();
}
```

This prints `ciao` as expected.